# Manually inflated TextView's resource string not displaying new lines (\n)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm inflating a TextView which references a resource string that contains newline characters (tried \n, \r\n, \n\n) that aren't displaying (get a long, truncated single line of text).

The code is as follows:

**Note:**
Currently the app is targeting an old version of Android (API 15/4.0.3, upgrade soon) and I just need to get a few bugs fixed for the time being. I have a 4.4 tablet I can try this on to see if it alleviates the issue.

**Calling Function**

---

```
public void ShowExitPromptDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
    OkDialogClickListener okListener = new OkDialogClickListener();

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    LinearLayout tv1 = (LinearLayout)li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_no_connectivity, null);

    builder.SetView(tv1)
            .SetPositiveButton("OK", okListener)                    
            .SetCancelable(true);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();
    dialog.Show();
}
```

**dialog_no_connectivity**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_noconnectivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/no_webservice_connectivity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Resources/Values/Strings.xml**

---

```
<string name="no_webservice_connectivity">1\n2\r\n3\n\nand to the 4
snoop doggy dog and super mario is at the door with your new switch beeotch!</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove

```
  android:singleLine="true"
```

such that it looks like

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_noconnectivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/no_webservice_connectivity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Burning off the rust, been a few years now.

Comment: Really though this was more of a general oversight than foggy memory. I should've been looking at all those settings, I just glanced at them. I make a lot of unintentional assumptions it is my achilles.

Answer (score 1):

Change android:singleLine="true" to android:singleLine="false" and add android:maxLines="6" (or more) in your TextView XML definition.

Comment: Kudo's goes to the more complete answer, sorry (also, singleLine defaults to false, so omitting it is sufficient). Thank you though, and the maxLines tip may actually be useful here since I got some formatting to do.